# login with facebook not working with php 5.2

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I try to set login with Facebook Plugin with simple core php code.

it gives me this error

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE - assumed 'CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE' 
in /home/public_html/facebook/src/base_facebook.php on line 997
```

my php version :

```
PHP Version 5.2.17
```

curl version is :

```
cURL support        : enabled
cURL Information    : libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
```

it seems the problem is in this function :

```
if ($result === false && empty($opts[CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE])) {
    $matches = array();
    $regex = '/Failed to connect to ([^:].*): Network is unreachable/';
    if (preg_match($regex, curl_error($ch), $matches)) {
      if (strlen(@inet_pton($matches[1])) === 16) {
        self::errorLog('Invalid IPv6 configuration on server, '.
                       'Please disable or get native IPv6 on your server.');
        self::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE] = CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
      }
    }
}
```

how do I run it ?
means what is the solution's of this error ?

Comment: yes i know this is duplicate but what is the solution of this problem ?

Comment: What the answer given there states …?

Comment: i use 000webhost.com for free hosting, and they are not update with php 5.3

Comment: facebook login is not supported with php 5.2 ?

Comment: Facebook don't care which version of PHP you use. But if you want to use their SDKs you have to use 5.3 for the old SDK and 5.4 for the new SDK. But you are free to write your own that works with 5.2